# Is this a "à¹‚à¸„à¹‰à¸1.5à¸¥à¸´à¸•à¸£(M)" UTF string or Ansi string

Tags: javascript, unicode, globalization, thai

I am not sure "à¹‚à¸„à¹‰à¸1.5à¸¥à¸´à¸•à¸£(M)" is UTF string or Ansi string. What is a reliable to detect it. This string should display thai characters properly.

Unless I understand its current encoding, I can not apply conversion to show thai characters properly.

Comment: @MarcoBonelli If it is UTF8 then why can't I see thai characters in it?

Comment: https://www.joelonsoftware.com/2003/10/08/the-absolute-minimum-every-software-developer-absolutely-positively-must-know-about-unicode-and-character-sets-no-excuses/

Answer (score 0):

It is double-encoded text. To reverse:

```
piconv -f utf8 -t latin1 -s "à¹‚à¸„à¹‰à¸1.5à¸¥à¸´à¸•à¸£(M)" | piconv -f iso-8859-11 -t utf8
เน?เธ?เน?เธ1.5เธฅเธดเธ?เธฃ(M)
```